# MySQL order of query

Tags: mysql, group-by, order-by

My query return like this.

```
12
14
14
99
78
78
54
```

I want result to be sorted so that no same number comes consecutively in the result. The result that I want is like this.

```
12
14
99
14
78
54
78
```

Comment: Put Your Query, question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post an example of your query? Without knowing what your query structure look likes, this will be difficult to fix. However here is an example that may point you in the right direction based off of your post title, in regards to `ORDER` and `GROUP`:

```
SELECT pkey,
       COUNT(int),
  FROM my_table
  LEFT JOIN this_table USING (key)
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY 2;
```